# Calculating the Laplacian of a Function Transformed by Polar Coordinates

Tags: real-analysis, analysis, multivariable-calculus

Let $(f: \mathbb{R}^2 \rightarrow \mathbb{R})$ be a function that is twice continuously partially differentiable, and let $(F: (0, \infty) \times \mathbb{R} \rightarrow \mathbb{R})$ be defined as $(F(r, \phi) = f(r \cos \phi, r \sin \phi))$. Show that for $((x, y)^t = r(\cos \phi, \sin \phi)^T)$, we have:

$
\Delta f(x, y) = \left(\frac{{\partial^2 F}}{{\partial r^2}} + \frac{1}{{r^2}} \frac{{\partial^2 F}}{{\partial \phi^2}} + \frac{1}{r} \frac{{\partial F}}{{\partial r}}\right)(r, \phi).
$

My solution:

$\textbf{Proof:}$

Let's consider the function $F(r, \phi) = f(r\cos\phi, r\sin\phi)$, where $f: \mathbb{R}^2 \rightarrow \mathbb{R}^2$ is a function that is twice continuously partially differentiable. We want to show that for $(x, y)^T = r(\cos\phi, \sin\phi)^T$, it holds that:

$
\Delta f(x, y) = \left(\frac{{\partial^2 F}}{{\partial r^2}} + \frac{1}{{r^2}} \frac{{\partial^2 F}}{{\partial \phi^2}} + \frac{1}{r} \frac{{\partial F}}{{\partial r}}\right)(r, \phi)
$

To prove this, we first calculate the Laplacian of $F$ using the chain rule. We have:

$
\frac{{\partial F}}{{\partial r}} = \frac{{\partial f}}{{\partial x}} \frac{{\partial (r\cos\phi)}}{{\partial r}} + \frac{{\partial f}}{{\partial y}} \frac{{\partial (r\sin\phi)}}{{\partial r}} = \frac{{\partial f}}{{\partial x}} \cos\phi + \frac{{\partial f}}{{\partial y}} \sin\phi
$
$
\frac{{\partial^2 F}}{{\partial r^2}} = \frac{{\partial}}{{\partial r}} \left(\frac{{\partial F}}{{\partial r}}\right) = \frac{{\partial}}{{\partial r}} \left(\frac{{\partial f}}{{\partial x}} \cos\phi + \frac{{\partial f}}{{\partial y}} \sin\phi\right) = \frac{{\partial^2 f}}{{\partial x^2}} \cos\phi + \frac{{\partial^2 f}}{{\partial y^2}} \sin\phi
$

Similarly, we calculate the second derivative of $F$ with respect to $\phi$:

$
\frac{{\partial F}}{{\partial \phi}} = \frac{{\partial f}}{{\partial x}} \frac{{\partial (r\cos\phi)}}{{\partial \phi}} + \frac{{\partial f}}{{\partial y}} \frac{{\partial (r\sin\phi)}}{{\partial \phi}} = -\frac{{\partial f}}{{\partial x}} r\sin\phi + \frac{{\partial f}}{{\partial y}} r\cos\phi
$

$
\frac{{\partial^2 F}}{{\partial \phi^2}} = \frac{{\partial}}{{\partial \phi}} \left(\frac{{\partial F}}{{\partial \phi}}\right) = \frac{{\partial}}{{\partial \phi}} \left(-\frac{{\partial f}}{{\partial x}} r\sin\phi + \frac{{\partial f}}{{\partial y}} r\cos\phi\right) = -\frac{{\partial^2 f}}{{\partial x^2}} r\sin\phi + \frac{{\partial^2 f}}{{\partial y^2}} r\cos\phi
$

Substituting these results back into the expression for the Laplacian, we obtain:

$
\Delta f(x, y) = \left(\frac{{\partial^2 f}}{{\partial x^2}} \cos\phi + \frac{{\partial^2 f}}{{\partial y^2}} \sin\phi + \frac{1}{{r^2}} \left(-\frac{{\partial^2 f}}{{\partial x^2}} r\sin\phi + \frac{{\partial^2 f}}{{\partial y^2}} r\cos\phi\right) + \frac{1}{r} \left(\frac{{\partial f}}{{\partial x}} \cos\phi + \frac{{\partial f}}{{\partial y}} \sin\phi\right)\right)(r, \phi)
$

Simplifying further, we get:

$
\Delta f(x, y) = \left(\frac{{\partial^2 f}}{{\partial x^2}} \cos\phi - \frac{{\partial^2 f}}{{\partial x^2}} \sin\phi + \frac{{\partial^2 f}}{{\partial y^2}} \sin\phi + \frac{{\partial^2 f}}{{\partial y^2}} \cos\phi + \frac{{\partial f}}{{\partial x}} \cos\phi + \frac{{\partial f}}{{\partial y}} \sin\phi\right)(r, \phi)
$
Finally, combining the terms, we have:

$
\Delta f(x, y) = \left(\frac{{\partial f}}{{\partial x}} + \frac{{\partial f}}{{\partial y}}\right)(r, \phi)
$

which simplifies to:

$
\Delta f(x, y) = \Delta f(r, \phi)
$

Therefore,  $\Delta f(x, y) = \Delta f(r, \phi)$

Is my proof correct?